# call jquery file function on html button click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to remove selected item from the list on button click.

```
 <input type="button" id="btnRemove" name="Remove" value="Remove" />
```

Jquery function in jquery file

```
$("#btnRemove").click(function() {
    $("#lst option:selected").remove();
});
```

Button remove click event is not firing, i have added jquery reference in asp.net page.

Comment: Where did you add the jquery reference in the page? Do you have your assignment of `$('#btnRemove').click()` inside a `document.ready()`, or is it happening before that element exists in the DOM?

Comment: jquery file reference is rigt at the bottom of asp.net page

Comment: are you sure the event is not firing or is it being called and not finding anything?

Answer (score 1):

are you sure the event is not firing or is it being called and not finding anything?

if it is not being called then i think you need to set the event up after the document is ready

try this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#btnRemove").click(function() {
            $("#lst option:selected").remove();
        });
});
```

if it is getting called(you should still do the above^) and not finding anything you need to tinker with that selector.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to make sure is

```
 <input type="button" id="btnRemove" name="Remove" value="Remove" onClick="RemoveSelected();" />

 function RemoveSelected(){
      $("#lst option:selected").remove();
 }
```